# unrealircd run at boot

Tags: ssh, startup-scripts

I have UnrealIRCD installed on my CentOS server. I'm not too familiar with startup scripts, so I'm wondering if it's possible to have it start when the vps starts up, or if it crashes, as well as start the Anope services, too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct (official) way to run unreal is via cron (the user you want to run as).

Open the crontab for the user that you wish to run unreal as, eg:

```
crontab -u user -e
```

And add this line:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * *   /home/user/ircd/Unreal3.2/ircdcron/ircdchk >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Adjust the path to match where your install of Unreal is.  If you have problems using VI as your default editor, google "linux editor environment variable."   If you have other problems, check the file /home/user/ircd/Unreal3.2/ircdcron/ircdchk - it should have been automatically generated to match the correct directory at install time.

Answer (score 0):

most simple way to do this would be placing the commands into the /etc/rc.local file. 
This will run after the system has been booted.

Please keep in mind that unrealIRC does not run as root, and the rc.local file will be executed as root.

Answer (score 0):

To make the jump that Goez did not make for you, here is the full command (using su) to run a command as a particular user, and in this instance, running UnrealIRCd as user "ircd":

```
su -c"/path/to/unreal/unreal start" ircd
```